# Script paths into Azure Data Factory DataLakeAnalytics u-sql pipeline

Tags: pipeline, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I'm trying to publish a data factory solution with this ADF **DataLakeAnalyticsU-SQL** pipeline activity following the azure step by step doc (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-usql-activity).

```
 {
    "type": "DataLakeAnalyticsU-SQL",
    "typeProperties": {
      "scriptPath": "\\scripts\\111_risk_index.usql",
      "scriptLinkedService": "PremiumAzureDataLakeStoreLinkedService",
      "degreeOfParallelism": 3,
      "priority": 100,
      "parameters": {
        "in": "/DF_INPUT/Consodata_Prelios_consegna_230617.txt",
        "out": "/DF_OUTPUT/111_Analytics.txt"
      }
    },
    "inputs": [
      {
        "name": "PremiumDataLakeStoreLocation"
      }
    ],
    "outputs": [
      {
        "name": "PremiumDataLakeStoreLocation"
      }
    ],

    "policy": {
      "timeout": "06:00:00",
      "concurrency": 1,
      "executionPriorityOrder": "NewestFirst",
      "retry": 1
    },
    "scheduler": {
      "frequency": "Minute",
      "interval": 15
    },
    "name": "ConsodataFilesProcessing",
    "linkedServiceName": "PremiumAzureDataLakeAnalyticsLinkedService"
  }
```

During publishing got this error:

```
25/07/2017 18:51:59- Publishing Project 'Premium.DataFactory'....
25/07/2017 18:51:59- Validating 6 json files
25/07/2017 18:52:15- Publishing Project 'Premium.DataFactory' to Data 
Factory 'premium-df'
25/07/2017 18:52:15- Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value
```

Trying to figure up what could be wrong with the project it came up that the issues reside into the activity options `"typeProperties"` as shown above, specifically for `scriptPath` and `scriptLinkedService` attributes. The doc says:

```
scriptPath: Path to folder that contains the U-SQL script. Name of the file 
is case-sensitive.  
scriptLinkedService: Linked service that links the storage that contains the 
script to the data factory
```

Publishing the project without them (using hard-coded `script`) it will complete successfully. The problem is that I can't either figure out what exactly put into them. I tried with several combinations paths. The only thing I know is that the script file must be referenced locally into the solution as a dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script linked service needs to be Blob Storage, not Data Lake Storage.

Ignore the publishing error, its misleading.

Have a linked service in your solution to an Azure Storage Account, referred to in the 'scriptLinkedService' attribute. Then in the 'scriptPath' attribute reference the blob container + path.

For example:

```
"typeProperties": {
  "scriptPath": "datafactorysupportingfiles/CreateDimensions - Daily.usql",
  "scriptLinkedService": "BlobStore",
  "degreeOfParallelism": 2,
  "priority": 7
},
```

Hope this helps.

Ps. Double check for case sensitivity on attribute names. It can also throw unhelpful errors.

Comment: It worked. Thank you. Shame for no documentation on this.

Comment: It all trial and error with new tech :-)
Personally I prefer to create my USQL as stored procedures in the logical ADLa database. Then call the procs from ADF.

Comment: Dear Fabio, I would also suggest to file a feature request against ADF to support scripts from ADLS accounts :)